# Chart.js Fill area between two lines with the color of the line that is higher

Tags: javascript, html, chart.js

I have a two line chart.js chart and looking to shade in the area between the two lines but only with the color of the line that is higher.

I already followed the following answer given here [Chart JS Fill Between two lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41467923/chart-js-fill-between-two-lines/41733045#41733045) to get the shading working but now need to change it a bit to get what I am looking for. I have attached a picture of what I am trying to do.

What I currently have:
[image]

And am looking to do something like this:
[image]

Here is the code I am using to do the shading:

```
var fillBetweenLinesPlugin = {
    afterDatasetsDraw: function (chart) {
        var ctx = chart.chart.ctx;
        var xaxis = chart.scales['x-axis-0'];
        var yaxis = chart.scales['y-axis-0'];
        var datasets = chart.data.datasets;
        ctx.save();

        for (var d = 0; d < datasets.length; d++) {
            var dataset = datasets[d];
            if (dataset.fillBetweenSet == undefined) {
                continue;
            }

            // get meta for both data sets
            var meta1 = chart.getDatasetMeta(d);
            var meta2 = chart.getDatasetMeta(dataset.fillBetweenSet);

            // do not draw fill if one of the datasets is hidden
            if (meta1.hidden || meta2.hidden) continue;

            // create fill areas in pairs
            for (var p = 0; p < meta1.data.length-1;p++) {
                // if null skip
              if (dataset.data[p] == null || dataset.data[p+1] == null) continue;

              ctx.beginPath();

              // trace line 1
              var curr = meta1.data[p];
              var next = meta1.data[p+1];
              ctx.moveTo(curr._view.x, curr._view.y);
              ctx.lineTo(curr._view.x, curr._view.y);
              if (curr._view.steppedLine === true) {
                ctx.lineTo(next._view.x, curr._view.y);
                ctx.lineTo(next._view.x, next._view.y);
              }
              else if (next._view.tension === 0) {
                ctx.lineTo(next._view.x, next._view.y);
              }
              else {
                  ctx.bezierCurveTo(
                    curr._view.controlPointNextX,
                    curr._view.controlPointNextY,
                    next._view.controlPointPreviousX,
                    next._view.controlPointPreviousY,
                    next._view.x,
                    next._view.y
                  );
                            }

              // connect dataset1 to dataset2
              var curr = meta2.data[p+1];
              var next = meta2.data[p];
              ctx.lineTo(curr._view.x, curr._view.y);

              // trace BACKWORDS set2 to complete the box
              if (curr._view.steppedLine === true) {
                ctx.lineTo(curr._view.x, next._view.y);
                ctx.lineTo(next._view.x, next._view.y);
              }
              else if (next._view.tension === 0) {
                ctx.lineTo(next._view.x, next._view.y);
              }
              else {
                // reverse bezier
                ctx.bezierCurveTo(
                  curr._view.controlPointPreviousX,
                  curr._view.controlPointPreviousY,
                  next._view.controlPointNextX,
                  next._view.controlPointNextY,
                  next._view.x,
                  next._view.y
                );
              }

                            // close the loop and fill with shading
              ctx.closePath();
              ctx.fillStyle = dataset.fillBetweenColor || "rgba(0,0,0,0.1)";
              ctx.fill();
            } // end for p loop
        }
    } // end afterDatasetsDraw
}; // end fillBetweenLinesPlugin
```